# Vba to open fourth excel file in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA code to open only the fourth Excel file in a folder regardless of the file’s name, do stuff on the file and close it

I have tried to use

```
Sub OpenDoStuff()

Dim fs As FileSearch
Dim i As Integer
Dim wbk As Workbook

Set fs = Application.FileSearch

With fs
.LookIn = "C:\Users\Saulo\Desktop\MINING"
.Filename = "*.xls"
For i = 3 To .Execute()
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(.FoundFiles(i))
    'do stuff here
wbk.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
End With
End Sub
```

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: 4th file based on what sort order?

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Filesearch` was removed from Excel in Office 2007. What version of Office are you using?

Assuming you really do have `Application.Filesearch` available:

```
Sub OpenDoStuff()

    Dim fs As FileSearch
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wbk As Workbook

    Set fs = Application.FileSearch

    With fs
    .LookIn = "C:\Users\Saulo\Desktop\MINING"
    .Filename = "*.xls"
    .Execute()

    If .FoundFiles.Count >= 4 Then
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(.FoundFiles(3))
       'do stuff here
        wbk.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You may be re right. I'm using Excel 2013 so I'll need a diferent code.

Answer (score 0):

Files need to be sorted.

I'm using WMI to get the files.  WMI will work on most environments.

DisplayFourthFile relies on a secondary function to sort the array.  You can easily replace the MsgBox with the opening of your file.

WMI doesn't support ORDER BY, hence the sort function.

```
Sub DisplayFourthFile()

    ' Get the Data, Unfortunately WMI Has No ORDER BY
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select Name from CIM_DataFile  where Drive='C:' and Path = '\\Users\\Saulo\\Desktop\\MINING\\' And Name Like '%XLS%'")

    ' Set to Array
    Dim files() As String
    ReDim files(1 To colFiles.count)
    Dim name As String
    Dim i As Integer: i = 1
    For Each objFile In colFiles
      files(i) = objFile.name
      i = i + 1
    Next

    ' Sort the Data
    QuickSort files, 1, colFiles.count

    If colFiles.count >= 4 Then

         Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(files(i))
         ' do stuff here
         wbk.Close(SaveChanges:=True)

    End If

    Set objWMIService = Nothing
    Set colFiles = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub QuickSort(vArray As Variant, inLow As Long, inHi As Long)

  Dim pivot   As Variant
  Dim tmpSwap As Variant
  Dim tmpLow  As Long
  Dim tmpHi   As Long

  tmpLow = inLow
  tmpHi = inHi

  pivot = vArray((inLow + inHi) \ 2)

  While (tmpLow <= tmpHi)

     While (vArray(tmpLow) < pivot And tmpLow < inHi)
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
     Wend

     While (pivot < vArray(tmpHi) And tmpHi > inLow)
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     Wend

     If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
        tmpSwap = vArray(tmpLow)
        vArray(tmpLow) = vArray(tmpHi)
        vArray(tmpHi) = tmpSwap
        tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
        tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
     End If

  Wend

  If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSort vArray, inLow, tmpHi
  If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSort vArray, tmpLow, inHi

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure where to insert the path to my file in this code. Plus I'm kind of new to VBA so I find this code a bit complicated.

Comment: I changed the WMI query to match your folder structure...and replaced the msgbox with your file open

Comment: I just did it. Take care.